# Dismiss UITableViewController on tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

Currently I have a UIView with a UItableview cell added to the subview, like so,[image]

When the button is pressed, it pushes to another navigation controller whos subclass is a uitableviewcontroller....

[image]

So When the user clicks on one of these tableviewcells... I want the viewcontroller to be poped from the navigation stack and go back to the previous view that is listed first.

I implemented the UITableviewcontroller method listed below with the following implementation.... but nothing occurs :P....

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are pushing the view controller onto the navigation controller's  stack i.e. `pushViewController:animated:`, you should pop out current view controller using `popViewControllerAnimated:` method.

If you want to go to a view controller not just one level below the current view controller (or top view controller in `UINavigationController`'s jargon), you can use `popToViewController:animated:`. And to go to the root view controller of the navigation controller, use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`.

But if you are presenting a view controller modally i.e. `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, then only you use the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` method to dismiss the presented view and go to the presenting view controller.

Comment: One more question.... how do I take that value of the cell.textlabel.text and pass it back to the first viewcontroller where the single cell is? I would like to update the first view's cell with the text of the selected cell in the pushed viewcontroller's tableviewcell...

Comment: Use delegation. Create a protocol and make the presenting view controller conform to it. Then on `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, send the delegate the required string or whatever message you want. Thats the best way to do it.

Comment: Kinda new to objective-c programming.. sorta... you think you can give a small example of what you mean? :/ sorry for being a complete newbie :P